# Post on Facebook/ twitter in background in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, twitter

Can anyone recommend me any `swift library to post on facebook and twiiter`.
I am trying this for now

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hasGranted("publish_actions")
    {
        print("publish actions already granted.")

    }
    else
    {
        FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me/feed", parameters: ["message" : "hello world"], HTTPMethod: "POST").startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error == nil))
            {
                print("Post id: \(result.valueForKey("id") as! String)")
            }
        })


    }
```

There is a situation that when user creates an event then my app will `automatically post/tweet` on its wall about the event he just created.

I am fimiliar about swifter and `Facebook SDK` but i am not sure if it will help me post in background

Comment: that´s not how it works on stackoverflow? what have you tried so far? where is your code? if you want your work done by other people, please go to a job platform and hire a developer.

Comment: that being said, autoposting (and prefilling the message) on facebook is not allowed anyway. you should know that, if you would be familiar with the facebook sdk - because you must have read the platform policy then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guys i know i asked a silly question , but after upgrading my project to swift 2.0 and fb sdk 4.6 i did the posting

```
var params: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
let userInfo: AnyObject =  LocalStore.userDetails()!
let name = userInfo["name"] as? String
params = ["message": msgString]
let request: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/feed", parameters: params as [NSObject: AnyObject], HTTPMethod: "POST")
request.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in })
```

This way you can post any message in background... but do check for fb login and ask for `publishPermission(loginWithPublishPermission)`.

Comment: If i want to post photo / message only to me/feed , do i need to get the approval of Facebook? I've tried but didn't succeed

Comment: sorry for extreme late reply, but yes you do not the approval

Answer (score 3):

How luschn said, you can't post automatically, but you can ask user if he want to post event.
For facebook post just use Facebook SDK(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios), you have there instruction for installation. You can use "Posting Data" from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph, but you need first to check if user give you right to post it.

For Twitter post, apple give you a library(Social.framework) can help you for post on Twitter. You can learn how use it from http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/social-framework-fundamentals--mobile-14333. Also you can use this framework for facebook post.